# How to get the historical floor price data of a specified NFT?

Tags: nft, price

How can I get historical prices for nft (Star atlas ships ).

I tried to search all transactions - but it is very expensive, and in general there is a limit of one thousand signatures.

I will be glad to get advice or help.